# ExecuteWithParams not working in welcome page

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have build an application using ADF & JDev 11.1.2.3.0,
When user performs a successful log-in he is redirected to the welcome-page of my application (lets say Page1). In Page1 I have some buttons that execute ExecuteWithParams operations. When I click in them nothing happens. It seems like no click was made. If I refresh the page and click again everything works fine. 
Does anyone know why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the jspx file directly?
Try running the page from the task-flow - basically right click the page in the diagram and choose run.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have a login page that in case of successful log-in redirects to Page1 in this case. This happens always when I deploy my application in glassfish but sometimes even in weblogic I get the same behavior. I cannot test what you are suggesting in glassfish case. Any other idea?